# RMS calculation in cheap microcontroller

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, rms

I normally see that RMS calculation is done using some kind of DSP or more high end microcontroller. I'm using [this microcontroller](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32g030c6.pdf) and I would like to know if it could do RMS.

I need to read 60 Hz current from a current transformer through an op-amp as shown below. I don't have values in the drawing because I'm just illustrating the concept. I've heard that one can use an external precision rectifier to sense the peak and calculate RMS from that. In my case I have the signal with a DC shift, and I think that doing RMS would be more robust against noise compared to just sensing the peak.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Look up how to actually calculate RMS for any arbitrary waveform, not just sine waves. That is why the use a DSP and you don't just measure the peak, hope it is a UNBIASED sine wave, and use a corresponding fudge factor.

Comment: It will involve integration.

Comment: That manual says you have a single cycle multiplier and a 60 MHz clock. That should be orders of magnitude more processing power than is needed to do real-time calculation of the RMS value of a ~60 Hz bandwidth signal.

Comment: The precision rectifier outputs the average, not the RMS.

Comment: @Lundin - presumably you meant 6kHz not 6Mhz. That is more than adequate as there is not much high-frequency noise above 3kHz with much energy.

Comment: @KevinWhite Ah yeah my bad. Then any SAC ADC will keep up just fine.

Comment: You might find the [Goertzel algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm) useful.